# Create nested schema with different payload fields

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

When creating a table with AWS Athena, we need to specify a schema, and it could be nested.

I'm trying to create a table called `events`. 
Each event will have a different payload, like the following:

```
{
 "event_name": "user_created",
 "when": "2019-01-01 14:00:00Z", 
 "payload": {
    "name": "John Raynolds",
    "age" 35,
    "likeable": true
  }
}

{
 "event_name": "user_matched",
 "when": "2019-01-10 19:32:19Z", 
 "payload": {
    "matching_id": 99877,
    "matcher_id":  99883,
    "matching_type": "friendship"
  }
}
```

So, as you can see in the previous json schema, the field `payload` differ from each type of event.
What is the best practice to handle these cases? Create one table per event type? Create all possible payload columns to the Athena schema definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options: either you do as you suggest and create columns for every possible payload column – that will work as long as the underlying data is JSON, but might not work for all data types (IIRC it won't work with ORC files, but don't take my word for it).

The other alternative is to simply type the `payload` column as `STRING` and use [JSON functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html) to work with it, for example:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.matching_type') AS matching_type,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM events
GROUP BY 1
```

If the payload only contains scalar values you could also use `MAP<STRING,STRING>` as the and use [map functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/map.html) to work with the values:

```sql
SELECT
  element_at(payload, 'matching_type') AS matching_type,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM events
GROUP BY 1
```